# Python - how to print entry text tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, tkinter-entry

I'm writing a basic Q&A program as I learn Python, and I'm messing around with tkinter's functions. I'm trying to print user input, but it just prints a blank line. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
def response():
    value = str(var.get())
    print(value)

root = Tk()
root.title("Bot")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "5 5 15 15")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0), sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

var = StringVar()

input_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=var)
input_entry.grid(column=5, row=5, sticky = (W, E))
input_entry.pack()

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=response).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E)) 
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Ask away!", command=response).grid(column=3,
row=3, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is a very well documented question. Consider searching before asking.

Answer (score 1):

To get an entry widgets text you can use `input_entry.get()`

You can see the documentation for the ttk entry widget [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm)

Comment: You're a lifesaver, Slayer! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Pythonista had it right. 
First problem is you tried to use both pack and grid in your entry widget.
The use of grid is a better fit. 
Second was you added parenthesis in the wrong place in your grid method.
Third issue I see is that when you create a Label and/or Button you should give
the label/button a name as you did with the entry widget. That way you will not run into 
problems later if you want to change the name of the label or button. Although the way you did it will work and is less code the results down the line will make less headaches for you in the long run. Below is an example of what I believe you should model your scripts like:

```
 from tkinter import *

 root = Tk()
 root.title("Title")
 root.geometry('300x100')


 def clear_text(self):
     txtE.delete(0, 'end')


 def new_label(event=None):
     Entree = txtE.get()
     lbl1['text'] = 'Hello There ' + Entree.title()
     clear_text(txtE)


 lbl1 = Label(root, text='Enter Your Name:)
 lbl1.pack()
 txtE = Entry(root)
 txtE.focus()
 txtE.pack()

 Button(root, text='Enter', command=new_label).pack()
 Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM)
 root.bind('<Return>', new_label)
 root.mainloop()
```